# Images are not rendered correctly

Tags: java, image, http, jakarta-ee

This code appears to work correctly, but when I use it to render a image from a database, the image is incomplete on the page. Only about the top 70% of the image was rendered. Different amounts of the images are rendered with different images.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    FileData fileData = new FileData();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    UploadFile uploadFile = fileData.SelectFile(id);
    inputStream = uploadFile.data;
    fileName = uploadFile.name;
    if(uploadFile.Type.equals("Image/Video"))
    {
        contentType = "image";
    }
    render(request, response);
}
private void render(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int inputStreamLength = 0;
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            inputStreamLength += length;
            baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        if (inputStreamLength > contentLength) {
            contentLength = inputStreamLength;
        }
        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.reset();
            httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
            httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(contentLength));
            httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "\"" + contentDisposition +
                                   "\"" + (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) !=
                                   null ? "; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"": "");
        }

        response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray(), 0, (int)contentLength);

        //finally
        response.getOutputStream().flush();

        //clear
        baos = null;
    }
    finally {
        close(response.getOutputStream());
        close(inputStream);
    }
}
private void close(Closeable resource) throws IOException {
    if (resource != null) {
        resource.close();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how the image looks on the page in Firefox.
[image: rendered image]

I have checked that the image doesn't get corrupted when uploaded to the site and the image is fine in the database. The problem is the code that render images on the site.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it, apparently variables don't reset on a new page load even if they are not static.